# How can I make proper request for the Identity Server Token Endpoint?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4, .net-6.0

I tried to send an api call to the identity server via .net 6 console application.

Here is the request:

```
   public static async Task<WorkflowResponse> PostRequestToIdentityAsync()
    {
        var url = "http://didentity/connect/token";
        IdentityRequestDataVM identityRequestDataVM = new IdentityRequestDataVM();
        identityRequestDataVM.username = "csm";
        identityRequestDataVM.password = "MjAyMjox";
        identityRequestDataVM.grant_type = "password";
        identityRequestDataVM.scope = "m_gln m_msd";

        string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(identityRequestDataVM);

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {


            var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = new Uri(url),
                Content = new StringContent(jsonString),
                Headers =
                {
                    {"X-Login","override"}
                }

            };

            var user = "gclt";
            var password = "glsrt";

            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{user}:{password}")));


            HttpResponseMessage message = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);


            if (message.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var contents = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                WorkflowResponse workflowResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WorkflowResponse>(contents);
                return workflowResponse;

            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }
        }

    }
```

But, it returned 400 err code (Bad request), is there any mistake in the code snippet ?

It is working fine with postman.

Comment: Maybe instead of user/password you need to have client_id and client_secret (?)

Comment: Also it looks like you are json-serializing your request, when it should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead

Comment: var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dict.Add("username", "csm");

Comment: Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict)